# Parallax scrolling with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, view, parallax, nestedscrollview

I have a layout that includes a NestedScrollView. Inside this view there is an ImageView that scrolls creating a parallax effect with the rest of the views. The ImageView scrolls at half the speed.

The problem is that I need the ImageView to do the parallax scrolling **only if it is within screen bounds**. If the ImageView is not inside of the visible part of the screen, I don't want it to react to the parallax code.

Is there a way to check if a view is within the visible part of the screen?

I thought maybe checking the view's scroll position, but I don't know how to compare it to the bottom of the visible screen.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt tried it yet but use this code,

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
yourView.getHitRect(bounds);
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect(yourScroll.getScrollX(),yourScroll.getScrollY(), 
            yourScroll.getScrollX() + yourScroll.getWidth(), yourScroll.getScrollY() + yourScroll.getHeight());
if(Rect.intersects(scrollBounds, bounds))
    {
        //is in visible part of the scrollview
    }
```

Comment: For some reason, the first imageview reacts to the parallax but the second doesn't. No matter how I change the scroll.

Is there a way to get a Rect with the visible screen's coordinates rather than the scrollview's?